# Python Crosstab Pivot Support

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

I have a dataframe in Python that contains the following info - call it "basket":

| Transaction | Category | Sales_Vol | Sales_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Everyday | 2 | 1.58 |
| 123 | Other | 3 | 3.97 |
| 789 | Everyday | 1 | 0.99 |
| 234 | Everyday | 1 | 0.79 |
| 579 | Everyday | 2 | 2.78 |
| 579 | Other | 2 | 3.28 |

I want to be to able to present this data in this format showing total Sales_Value.

A couple of examples:

- The total value of transactions containing one "Everyday" and zero "Other" is 0.99 + 0.79 = 1.78.
- The total value of transactions containing two "Everyday" and three "Other" is 1.58 + 3.97 = 5.55.

| Vols | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1.78 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 6.06 | 5.55 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I think the solution will involve a pivot or cross tab but can't quite figure it out. Any help really appreciated!

Cheers,
SL

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question!  Here is one method to return the desired result (explanation of steps within code):

```py
# split everyday and other to two columns
sales_vol = df.set_index(["Transaction", "Category"])["Sales_Vol"] \
    .unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)

# dictionary of total sales values for each transaction
sales_val = df.groupby("Transaction")["Sales_Value"].sum().to_dict()

# create pivot table and map Transaction with sales_val dict
df1 = sales_vol.reset_index().pivot_table(
    columns="Other", index="Everyday",
    values="Transaction",
    aggfunc=lambda x: sum(list(map(sales_val.get, list(x)))))

# reindex to all integers in range, fillna with 0.
df1 = df1 \
    .reindex(range(0, df1.index.max()+1), axis=0) \
        .reindex(range(0, df1.columns.max()+1), axis=1) \
            .fillna(0)
# Other        0    1     2     3
# Everyday                       
# 0         0.00  0.0  0.00  0.00
# 1         1.78  0.0  0.00  0.00
# 2         0.00  0.0  6.06  5.55
```